# How to use functions found inside pluggable.php with my plugin files

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Am creating a plugin and needed to use get_user_by() and wp_check_password() and some cool functions available in the wordpress  pluggable.php but it always throw an undefined function error.

But if i include the file directly in my plugin file like this

```
include (ABSPATH . 'wp_includes/pluggable.php')
```

I will be able to use those functions in my plugin but i read that is not good to include such files directly, so am seeking to know best way to do it without conflicts.
I have also tried creating a function like this

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'show');
function show() {
$user = get_user_by('ID', 1);
return $user;
}
```

Yet is not working.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't explicitly require pluggables.php in your plugin. The whole point of them is that they are overridable by plugins, and if you load them before a plugin which does want to override one then that will fail. The loading sequence is (see [wp-settings.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5.1/wp-settings.php#L374)):

- load active plugins
- `require pluggable.php`
- `do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );`

so pluggable functions are available from the plugins_loaded action onwards. This will cover almost all WordPress hooks you're likely to want to use:

- If you want your plugin to do something at load time that uses a pluggable function then put the logic in a plugins_loaded handler
- else put the logic in the appropriate action handler or filter

and it'll work fine.

---

And for what it's worth your example does work fine for me. I dropped [this script](https://gist.github.com/RupW/fc78981c300b6e4d1e95c0342be5b299) into my mu-plugins folder (which is loaded before plugins) and

- I don't get any errors from the `get_user_by` call
- Your version doesn't do anything observable so I've added an `error_log()` call

  ```
  error_log( print_r( $user, true ) );
  ```

  and I do see my user 1 logged to my server error log correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the typo but using uppercase for ID in get_user_by() works well thats how is used.

Comment: The returned value is an array of user data like user_login, user_pass, ID, user_email and so on, am not particular about returning the value for now i know how to get that, i just want to use the function without including pluggable files, so some reasons i don't know why plugins_loaded handler is not working

Comment: OK, fair enough about ID: it is lower case 'id', and all the get_user_by calls in WordPress itself use lower-case (e.g. in pluggable, class-wp-rest-users-controller), but there is code in [class-wp-user](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp-user.php#L191) that changes 'ID' to 'id'.

Comment: Yes both id and ID works but why is plugins_loaded not working. And secondly there are many functions i would love to use that is in the pluggable, does it mean i have to create action handlers for each of them?

Comment: It does work for me. You can use all of them but only after the plugins_loaded event has fired. Which means you can use them in pretty much any action handler or filter.